# Connection refused by MongoDb from docker-hub

Tags: mongodb, docker

I run the MongoDB docker. But don't accept connections !!!

I run the MongoDB docker (on a VirtualBox virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 18.10:

```
$ sudo docker run --name myMongoDb -v /home/utente/myApp/datiMyApp:/data/db -d mongo
```

But don't accept connections !!!

I had look the log of the docker, but I think is ok:

```
$ sudo docker logs myMongoDb

chown: cannot dereference '/proc/1/fd/1': Permission denied
chown: cannot dereference '/proc/1/fd/2': Permission denied
2019-01-24T09:43:30.315+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=0a05c1774000
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.5
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-01-24T09:43:30.318+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
2019-01-24T09:43:30.321+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2019-01-24T09:43:30.322+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-01-24T09:43:30.322+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-01-24T09:43:30.322+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3476M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-01-24T09:43:31.374+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1548323011:374721][1:0x7fbda0043a40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-01-24T09:43:31.794+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019-01-24T09:43:32.707+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-24T09:43:32.707+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-01-24T09:43:32.707+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-01-24T09:43:32.708+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-24T09:43:32.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: c47351e0-1fc5-4a06-a965-bde9fbca93f3
2019-01-24T09:43:33.041+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0
2019-01-24T09:43:33.044+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 3280ba64-7e0c-4599-8e3a-60f96a3ec26e
2019-01-24T09:43:33.313+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2019-01-24T09:43:33.314+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2019-01-24T09:43:33.314+0000 I STORAGE  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] createCollection: config.system.sessions with generated UUID: 21056e12-839f-4ee2-8616-09e3edec0e30
2019-01-24T09:43:34.657+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index on: config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 }
2019-01-24T09:43:34.657+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh]     building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-01-24T09:43:34.712+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2019-01-24T09:43:34.712+0000 I COMMAND  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] command config.$cmd command: createIndexes { createIndexes: "system.sessions", indexes: [ { key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 } ], $db: "config" } numYields:0 reslen:114 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } } } protocol:op_msg 1398ms
```

I tried to install the mongodb-clients on the vm and tried a connection with:

$ mongo

But I get the error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2019-01-24T10:46:53.707+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2019-01-24T10:46:53.707+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expose the port in your docker container:

```
 $ sudo docker run -p27017:27017 --name myMongoDb -v /home/utente/myApp/datiMyApp:/data/db -d mongo
```

By default no ports are routed to the host system.